# C# WCF: WCF Service returning a (404) Bad Request when sending an array of items

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to send an array of about 50 elements to a WCF service method, but I'm always receiving a `(404) Bad Request` error.

I think that it has to do with the message size or something like that, because if I send an empty array it works.

I did some research and added some stuff in the web.config of the WCF but I still can't manage to get this to work.

Can anyone please provide some additional information as to how I can maybe **increase the size of the message I can send**?

---

**[UPDATE] Solution:**

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740039/c-wcf-wcf-service-returning-a-404-bad-request-when-sending-an-array-of-items/740087#740087)

Comment: if i send 5 elements of the array, I still get the bad request error

Comment: then its not the size, try focusing on the contents of your array.

Comment: but, if i send 3, it works; that's why I'm conferenced about the size

Comment: oh hmm then maybe its size related indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid, stupid me :(

The thing is that I was creating the binding configuration in the web.config like such:

```
<bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBindingConfig" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"  maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6000000">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="6000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

But then I was not applying the configuration to the endpoint!  So, I had to add this to the endpoint tag:

```
bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig"
```

Now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

It's an obvious one but have you tried setting [MaxReceivedMessageSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.transportbindingelement.maxreceivedmessagesize.aspx) to 65536 and  seeing if it still fails?

Answer (score 0):

Your service host should be configured to recieve large set of data, if not, it is either dropped at service level.

- Add reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.
- When creating the binding set the message size:

  ```
  return new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None, true)  
  {  
      MaxReceivedMessageSize = 99999999,  
      ReaderQuotas = { MaxArrayLength = 99999999 }  
  };
  ```