# Not able to send long string to WCF ,the remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, web-services, wcf

I am sending a very long string to service which at present is `318771` characters long.
I am getting an error `The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.`

** CLIENT APP.CONFIG **

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_INBFC" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000"
                maxArrayLength="200000000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                    realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

** SERVICE APP.CONFIG **

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization"/>
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel"/>
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel.Web"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>



          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651143/the-remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-400-bad-request)

Answer (score 0):

A case of malformed request from [W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.1)

Check if the service is able to recieve the request using SOAP UI, also check if the datatypes between server and client calls match.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your issue involves the WCF binding configuration.  In particular, the `maxReceivedMessageSize` value and/or the `readerQuota` settings. If you provide your client/server bindings (or the entire relevant sections of the configuration file, we could provide better guidance.)

Note: you may want to enable WCF tracing, if you have not already, to help determine the cause of the issue.  Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your service configuration does not show the service definition or the service bindings, so it is hard to tell if the maxReceivedMessageSize value and/or the readerQuota settings on the service match the client.