# WCF 400 Bad Request for Large Data

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

I am developing a REST service in .NET 4.0 and here is my web.config file
I an new to .NET and have been struggling for two days to understand why I am not able to upload data more than ~60KB.

I understood by googling that that the BufferSize has to be increased and tried modifing web.config file in different ways which never worked. Can someone help me.

Regards
Hitesh

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>   <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
       <assemblies>
         <add assembly="System.Data.Entity,
 Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
       </assemblies>
     </compilation> <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576"/>  
 </system.web>   <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
       <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
     </modules>   </system.webServer>   <system.serviceModel>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
     <standardEndpoints>
       <webHttpEndpoint>
         <!-- 
             Configure the WCF REST service base address via the
 global.asax.cs file and the default
 endpoint 
             via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
         -->
         <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"
 automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
 />
       </webHttpEndpoint>
     </standardEndpoints> <services>

 <service name=""
 behaviorConfiguration="UpdateRealtimeWebPortfolioStructure.Service1Behavior"
 > <!-- Service Endpoints -->

 <endpoint address=""
 binding="wsHttpBinding"
 contract="UpdateRealtimeWebPortfolioStructure.IService1"
 bindingConfiguration="higherMessageSize_WS"><!--
 Upon deployment, the following
 identity element should be removed or
 replaced to reflect the

 identity under which the deployed
 service runs. If removed, WCF will
 infer an appropriate identity

 automatically.

 --> <identity>

 <dns value="localhost" /> </identity>

 </endpoint> <endpoint address="mex"
 binding="mexHttpBinding"
 contract="IMetadataExchange"
 bindingConfiguration="higherMessageSize_MEX"/>

 </service> </services>

 <bindings> <wsHttpBinding>

 <binding name="higherMessageSize_WS"
 closeTimeout="10:01:00"

 openTimeout="10:01:00"
 receiveTimeout="10:10:00"
 sendTimeout="10:01:00"

 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
 transactionFlow="false"
 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"

 maxBufferPoolSize="524288000"
 maxReceivedMessageSize="65536000"
 messageEncoding="Text"

 textEncoding="utf-8"
 useDefaultWebProxy="true"
 allowCookies="false"></binding>
 </wsHttpBinding>

 <mexHttpBinding> <binding
 name="higherMessageSize_MEX" />

 </mexHttpBinding>


 </bindings><behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>

 <behavior name=""> <!-- To avoid
 disclosing metadata information, set
 the value below to false and remove
 the metadata endpoint above before
 deployment -->

 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"
 /> <dataContractSerializer
 maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>

 <!-- To receive exception details in
 faults for debugging purposes, set the
 value below to true. Set to false
 before deployment to avoid disclosing
 exception information -->
 <serviceDebug
 includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"
 />

 </behavior> </serviceBehaviors>

 </behaviors>   </system.serviceModel> 
 <connectionStrings>
     <add name="GeoContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Geo.csdl|res://*/Geo.ssdl|res://*/Geo.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
 connection string=&quot;Data
 Source=YQLABSSERVER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial
 Catalog=Geo;Integrated
 Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
 providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
 />   
 </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: I formatted the XML but maybe you can remove all but the relevant part? And post some of the interface, are we talking Streams, big arrays, .... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784606/large-wcf-web-service-request-failing-with-400-http-bad-request?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I think the only configuration changes of system.serviceModel required for increasing message size in REST scenario using ASP.NET compatibility are:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <!-- default binding configration used for all REST services -->
    <webHttpBinding>
      <!-- max allowed message size incresed to 500 000 Bytes -->
      <binding maxBufferSize="500000" maxReceivedMessageSize="500000" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I got solution by adding maxBufferSize headers to <serviceEndPoint> tag. It works fine now

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by adding maxBufferSize headers to `<serviceEndPoint>` tag. It works fine now