# Bad request invalid URL

Tags: c#, wcf, url, web-config

I've noticed that when I enter a URL to my WCF, I get the response correctly if it's below 410 characters long. As I add the 410:th character in the URL line, I get 400 - bad URL.

I increased the max length of URL line as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245843/how-do-i-increase-the-maxurllength-property-in-the-config-in-asp-net-mvc-3) in my config file. To no avail.

What do I miss? What can be done?

It should work as decribed [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419985/wcf-url-length-causing-iis-400-bad-request-error). I'm probably doing something wrong. This is my config-part.

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="4096"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
```

Is that something that can be set in behaviors? Or on endpoints?!