# Wcf rest service URL max length

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, iis

I have rest wcf service working okay.
Except in some scenarios It throws bad request.

On some search and checks, it seems when the url has longer parameters.(sometimes url length is more than 1000) .It does not hit the service and thrown bad request straight away.

```
http://testservice/Service.svc/endpoint/get/1/2/longparameter
```

How can I address for such situations?

Comment: Don't use such a long URL...

Comment: It's required.any other way of shortening the value of parameter(compressing)? it can be considered

Comment: You can send data within the body of the request.

Comment: you can set max data length from IIS too to handle this

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419985/wcf-url-length-causing-iis-400-bad-request-error) was able to resolve it by adding the following:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="500" />
</system.web>
```

That worked for me, but in your case it sounds like you'd need to set it even higher.