# WCF service 400 bad request

Tags: .net, wcf, exception

I've created a service to receive large files. After that  I've published it on my local IIS7. After that I've created test client with service reference. When I trying to send large file to server I've got: **Bad request (400)**.

Service tracing of that exception:
**The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.**

Server config:

```
  <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" executionTimeout="14400"/>
<customErrors mode="Off" /></system.web>
```

Binding

```
      <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsBufferedHttpsBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="11534336" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
             sendTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" closeTimeout="00:05:00" >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="11534336" maxArrayLength="11534336"
          maxBytesPerRead="11534336" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Service

```
      <service name="MyService">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingName="wsBufferedHttpsBinding"
              contract="IServiceContract">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="soap12IssuedToken" binding="customBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="soap12IssuedToken" name="soap12IssuedToken"
      bindingNamespace="http://url"
      contract="IServiceContract" />
  </service>
```

What the hell wrong with this service? I set this message size everywhere.

Comment: How large are the files to be transferred?  It may help to use [streaming with the http binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx).

Comment: Forgot to say - it's fail while 1mb file sending.

Comment: I found this very interesting comment about that propblem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4808527/383187. But in my tracking there is no 'No Endpoint found' messages

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the main problem is that your endpoint does not reference a binding configuration. You are therefore using the default 65536.

There are a few other things to check:

- You have 2 endpoints for the same contract are you using the one where maxReceivedMessageSize is set?
- Does the configuration on the client match that on the server?
- You may also need to set "maxBufferPoolSize" and "maxBufferSize"

Answer (score 0):

Answer is quite simple:

```
 <endpoint address=""
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingName="wsBufferedHttpsBinding"
          contract="IServiceContract">
```

I did not see that there is **bindingName** instead of **bindingConfiguration**

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this problem later, but then i solved it by adding the
**dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"** in the **behaviour** of the service